# Calculator Functionality

Tags: swiftui, calculator

I’m working on a dilution calculator. I have it 98% working, however, I want it to work a certain way and I’m not sure to do that. This is my first app so I’m new at this.

So I want the user to be able to input the numbers and hit a button to get the calculation. I’ve been using @State and through my research and understanding, using that instantly updates any changes the user makes.

So how do I go about making the app wait till the user hits the “Go” button.

Hers my code so far.

```
@State private var ContainerSize = 0
@State private var DilutionRatio = 0
@State private var Go = ""
@State private var TotalProduct = 0.0
@State private var TotalWater = 0.0

@FocusState private var amountIsFocused: Bool   

    var totalProductAmount: Double {       

        let firstValue = Double(ContainerSize)
        let secondValue = Double(DilutionRatio + 1)

        let totalProduct = Double(firstValue / secondValue)

    return totalProduct

    }

    var totalWaterAmount: Double {

        let firstValue = Double(ContainerSize)
        let secondValue = Double(DilutionRatio + 1)

        let totalWater = Double(firstValue - secondValue)

    return totalWater

    }
       
//Container Size

                ZStack {
                    Image("Container Size (Oz)")
                        .padding(.vertical, -15)
                    TextField("", value: $ContainerSize, format: .number)
                        .frame(width: 200.0, height: 60.0)
                        .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
                        .font(Font.system(size: 50, design: .default))
                        .keyboardType(.decimalPad)
                        .focused($amountIsFocused)
                }
            }

//Dilution Ratio

            ZStack {
                Image("Dilution Ratio - 2")
                    .padding(.vertical, -10)
                TextField("", value: $DilutionRatio, format: .number)
                    .frame(width: 200.0, height: 60.0)
                    .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
                    .font(Font.system(size: 50, design: .default))
                    .keyboardType(.decimalPad)
                    .focused($amountIsFocused)
            }

//Go Button

            Button(action: {}, label: {
                Image("Go Button")
            })

//Results

            HStack{            
                ZStack {
                    Image("Total Product (Oz)")
                    Text("\(totalProductAmount, specifier: "%.1f")")
                        .font(Font.system(size: 60, design: .default))
                }               

                ZStack {
                    Image("Total Water (Oz)")
                    Text(totalWaterAmount, format: .number)
                        .font(Font.system(size: 60, design: .default))
                }
                .toolbar {
                    ToolbarItemGroup(placement: .keyboard) {
                        Spacer(
                        Button("Done") {
                            amountIsFocused = false
    }

}

struct CalculatorIView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        CalculatorIView()
}

}
```

The calculator works as is but I want the user to input numbers, hit the “Go” button, and the results are shown.

Comment: as you have it now the user doesn't need to hit go, as the results are automatically updated if the input fields are changed. Is that what you want, or do you specifically only want to calculate on button push?

Comment: you're only missing `var body: some view` before the views, and probably want to put all views in an overall VStack.

Comment: @ChrisR I specifically only want to calculate on button push. I know that it works the way that it is now with the results automatically updating, but I want the button push.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So far you do the calculation in calculated properties and display them directly. So they'll update every time one of their underlying @State values change.

If you only want to show results on button press, you should display your @State result vars, and update inside the button action.

Side note: property names should start lowercase.

[image]

```
struct ContentView: View {
    // side note: var names should start lowerCase
    @State private var containerSize = 0
    @State private var dilutionRatio = 0
    @State private var totalProduct = 0.0
    @State private var totalWater = 0.0
    
    // for clarity change calculations to funcs
    func totalProductAmount() -> Double {
        let firstValue = Double(containerSize)
        let secondValue = Double(dilutionRatio + 1)
        let totalProduct = Double(firstValue / secondValue)
        return totalProduct
    }
    
    func totalWaterAmount() -> Double {
        let firstValue = Double(containerSize)
        let secondValue = Double(dilutionRatio + 1)
        let totalWater = Double(firstValue - secondValue)
        return totalWater
    }
    
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            //Container Size
            Text("Container Size (Oz)")
                .padding(.vertical, -15)
            TextField("", value: $containerSize, format: .number)
                .frame(width: 200.0, height: 60.0)
                .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
                .font(Font.system(size: 50, design: .default))
                .keyboardType(.decimalPad)
            
            
            //Dilution Ratio
            Text("Dilution Ratio - 2")
                .padding(.vertical, -10)
            TextField("", value: $dilutionRatio, format: .number)
                .frame(width: 200.0, height: 60.0)
                .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
                .font(Font.system(size: 50, design: .default))
                .keyboardType(.decimalPad)
            
            //Go Button
            Button(action: {
                // Calculate here, and set State vars with results
                totalProduct = totalProductAmount()
                totalWater = totalWaterAmount()
            }, label: {
                Text("Go Button")
            })
            .buttonStyle(.borderedProminent)
            .padding()
            
            //Results
            // Show the state vars, not the calculation vars!
            HStack{
                VStack {
                    Text("Total Product (Oz)")
                    Text("\(totalProduct, specifier: "%.1f")")
                        .font(Font.system(size: 60, design: .default))
                }
                
                VStack {
                    Text("Total Water (Oz)")
                    Text(totalWater, format: .number)
                        .font(Font.system(size: 60, design: .default))
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much. This is what exactly what I was looking for. Thanks for breaking it down and explaining it. One last question if that's ok. How do I leave the text field for the "Container Size" and Dilution Ratio" blank. Right now it displays a zero. Or can you make it disappear when it's tapped on to enter a number. Thanks.

Comment: Happy to help:) if my answer was satisfying please check is as correct.

To your other question: If you use `TextField(value: format:)` you can directly enter numbers, but it will always show a "0" as empty input. You can avoid that by using TextField with a string input, but then you'll have to convert that string to a number afterwards.

Comment: Hi again, I wanted to ask, how can I add a button to “reset” the textfields and results back to zero. Thanks.

Comment: Well, just do what you described: Add another Button that sets all vars to 0.

Answer (score 1):

You can create func for calculation and call it from button action. You should remove calculated properties, var totalProductAmount: Double and var totalWaterAmount: Double and do the calculation inside the function. You can check the example below.

https://www.hackingwithswift.com/quick-start/swiftui/how-to-create-a-tappable-button

```
var body: some View{
    Button(action: {
                someCalculation()
            }, label: {
            Image("Go Button")
           })
}

func someCalculation(){
     // do some calculation and you can set @State variables or you can return some value. For example 'func someCalculation()->Double'
}
```